# Pandas explode error - column must be scalar

Tags: python, pandas, explode

```
df.explode(['X'])


ValueError: column must be a scalar
```

Hi anyone could advice on this?

Comment: Why did you think to use `['x']` and not `'x'`?

Comment: @Tonz I know this is an old question but if you feel an answer solved the problem, please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the green check mark. This helps keep the focus on older SO questions which still don't have answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `df.explode('X')` instead of `df.explode(['X'])`. Example on pandas [explode page](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) explains this.

Answer (score 12):

You can supply a list or tuple of column names, but only with pandas >= 1.3.0:  see https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html

> New in version 1.3.0: Multi-column explode

If you see this `ValueError` you must be using an older version of pandas

Answer (score 1):

For those of you working with Pandas < 1.3, the following logic executes a multi-column explode and is reasonably efficient. Just need to replace the name of cols you want to explode.

```
def explode(df):
    df['tmp']=df.apply(lambda row: list(zip(row[col1],row[col2])), axis=1) 
    df=df.explode('tmp')
    df[[col1,col2]]=pd.DataFrame(df['tmp'].tolist(), index=df.index)
    df.drop(columns='tmp', inplace=True)
    return df
```

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the function signature for `explode`, it has to be a scalar column name (either a `str` or a `tuple`), and you are passing a `list`.

Example

```
df = pd.DataFrame(index=['a', 'b'], 
                  data={'col1': [[10, 11]], 'col2': [[1, 2]]})

>>>df.explode('col1')                                                                                              
  col1    col2
a   10  [1, 2]
a   11  [1, 2]
b   10  [1, 2]
b   11  [1, 2]

>>>df.explode(['col1'])
ValueError: column must be a scalar
```