# Create DataFrame columns based on another columns (faster solution)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a `DataFrame` with 1mln of rows and two columns `Type` and  `Name` whose values are a lists with non-unique values. Both `Type` and `Name` columns have the same number of elements because they form a pair (`Type`, `Name`). I would like to add to my `DataFrame` columns whose names are the unique types from `Type` column with the values being a list of corresponding values from `Name` columns. Below is a short example of the current code. It works but very slow when the number of rows is 1mln so I'm looking for a faster solution.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"Type": [["1", "1", "2", "3"], ["2","3"]], "Name": [["A", "B", "C", "D"], ["E", "F"]]})

unique = list(set(df["Type"].explode()))
for t in unique:
    df[t] = None
    df[t] = df[t].astype('object')

for idx, row in df.iterrows():
    for t in unique:
        df.at[idx, t] = [row["Name"][i] for i in range(len(row["Name"])) if row["Type"][i] == t]
```

My desired result is:
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can explode the whole dataframe and then use your exploded dataframe and pivot it with a `list` as the aggfunc (Resetting the index to use the index as the grouper for the pivot)

```
df.explode(column=['Type','Name']).reset_index().pivot_table(index='index',columns='Type', values='Name',aggfunc=list)

Type    1       2   3
index           
0       [A, B]  [C] [D]
1       NaN     [E] [F]
```

And then concat it back onto the original

```
pd.concat([df,df.explode(column=['Type','Name']).reset_index().pivot_table(index='index',columns='Type', values='Name',aggfunc=list)],axis=1)

    Type            Name            1       2   3
0   [1, 1, 2, 3]    [A, B, C, D]    [A, B]  [C] [D]
1   [2, 3]          [E, F]          NaN     [E] [F]
```

As requested, here is the code broken out by step for debugging purposes

```
df1=df.explode(column=['Type','Name'])
df1=df1.reset_index()
pvt=df1.pivot_table(index='index',columns='Type', values='Name',aggfunc=list)
pd.concat([df,pvt],axis=1)
```

Comment: I'm getting "ValueError: column must be a scalar"

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce. The data you provided in the question produces the desired result. At what step do you get that error? You can break the first step in my code into multiple steps, first explode, then reset index, then pivot it and see where the issue occurs

Comment: Can you add the entire code? The explode() function returns this error

Comment: According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61313268/pandas-explode-error-column-must-be-scalar) you may need to update your pandas version to allow you to pass a list of columns to explode

Answer (score 2):

Alternative solution:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({"Type": [["1", "1", "2", "3"], ["2","3"]], "Name": [["A", "B", "C", "D"], ["E", "F"]]})
df_conc = pd.concat([df, df.apply(pd.Series.explode).reset_index().groupby(['index', 'Type']).agg(list).unstack().droplevel(level=0, axis=1).fillna("").apply(list)], axis=1)
df_conc

----------------------------------------------
    Type           Name         1       2   3
0   [1, 1, 2, 3]   [A, B, C, D] [A, B]  [C] [D]
1   [2, 3]         [E, F]               [E] [F]
----------------------------------------------
```

If `nan` values are accepted, just remove `.fillna("").apply(list)`:

```py
df_conc = pd.concat([df, df.apply(pd.Series.explode).reset_index().groupby(['index', 'Type']).agg(list).unstack().droplevel(level=0, axis=1)], axis=1)
df_conc

----------------------------------------------
    Type           Name         1       2   3
0   [1, 1, 2, 3]   [A, B, C, D] [A, B]  [C] [D]
1   [2, 3]         [E, F]       NaN     [E] [F]
----------------------------------------------
```